# Systemd custom service doesn't read PATH

Tags: systemd, path, services, node.js

I am trying to run a Node.js app as a service in Debian 9. So, following some tutorials, I've made a service like that.

```
[Unit]
Description=bumer API Http Server
[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/bumer-service.pid
User=root
Group=root
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
WorkingDirectory=/root/bumer/
SyslogIdentifier=bumer
ExecStart=/root/bumer/app.js
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My app has `#!/usr/bin/env node` as its first line and it runs pretty well if I run the command `/root/bumer/app.js`.
The problem is that when I start the service I was getting the following error:

```
main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
```

So, I tried to change the first line of the app.js file to the node's path instead of the word "node" `#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.11.4/bin/node` and now it's running fine.
I guess the service is not reading the PATH variable and I need some help to realize why it doesn't.

(my PATH is right and when I run "type node" the result is OK).

```
root@bumer:~# type node
node is /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.11.4/bin/node
```

(I am logging the variable PORT which I set on ~/.bashrc on the app.js but it cannot read as well, it logs `undefined`).

Answer (score 3):

## Services do not run in login session contexts.

Your `PATH` is *not* right, and the value of `PATH` in a shell in a login session is completely irrelevant, as are your shell's startup scripts.

One of the features of service management systems (in general, not limited to systemd) is that they start all services based upon a single uniform environment, as modified *only* by elements of the service definition (whatever that is).  It is nothing to do with how login shells set up user environments for login sessions.  (Not, it is not `root`'s login session environment either.)

In systemd's case, your service definition is the service unit file, and unless you modify `PATH` in that unit it will be whatever default value *that all services are started with*.  In systemd's case, this is documented; and `/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.11.4/bin/` is *not* on the list.

If you want `PATH` to be something other than the all-serviecs default, you need to modify your service unit with `Environment=` settings to change it.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al. (2017).  "[Environment variables in spawned processes](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes)".  *systemd.exec*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.